# Collection items don't trigger product load event observers or backend models, but can they?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm reposting this from magento.stackexchange because of practically no views/answers there.

We have an observer that modifies final price, that's triggered on the event `catalog_product_get_final_price`. Problem is, when you retrieve products via collection with `addAttributeToSelect("*")`, they come back with a `final_price` already set, and the product `getFinalPrice` function merely returns what's in the database instead of recalculating (and running the observers for) the final price.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
{
    // *** Collection items already have a 'final_price' from flat tables
    //     but it's wrong because observers haven't run yet ***
    $price = $this->_getData('final_price');
    if ($price !== null) {
        return $price;
    }
    return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
}
```

I've also noticed that all of our custom attributes are also not being interpreted (we save things as JSON but decode into objects them on product load before using them).

This behavior doesn't happen when you load the product directly -- all the observers and models are interpreted when the product is loaded.

**Is there a way to ensure the data we're retrieving from a collection matches in format and value the data we would retrieve if we load the product directly?**

I know I can just load the product individually to trigger all of the events that go along with it, but in the case of 3rd party software, that might not always be the case and the final price is wrong.

We're on version 1.7 if it helps.

Comment: you can override the getFinalPrice method, the collections grab final_price from the indexes, as you noticed

Comment: I'm really hoping there's a better way of handling this than overloading a core function. No built in functionality to ensure the `final_price` returned by the `product` object includes code from observers or backend models?

Comment: yes, but you would have to iterate the collection to set the final price that you want, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Set up an event

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <modulename>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Seamus_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>changePrice</method>
        </modulename>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

On your observer do something like...

```
public function changePrice($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $products = $observer->getCollection();

    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        $product->setFinalPrice( $this->getPriceLogic($product) );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Argh, yeah, it's *a* solution, but man is it ugly. Essentially it means looping over every collection twice: once when you load it to remove/update the price data and a second time to do whatever you normally do with the collection. I was really hoping Magento had something a little more elegant built in.

Comment: there's no loads though, it should be reasonably fast as long as you're not loading extra data from the database on the loop

Comment: I stumbled upon this today while in a nearly identical situation, and am deciding to go with this event observer as well. I am modifying my final price while observing `catalog_product_load_after` and unfortunately this doesn't fire at all from models loaded from a collection. Regarding the "looping twice" concern, this is already happening whether you like it or not. If you take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_afterLoad()` this method iterates through all the products in the collection as well. So there's 1 loop around the products before you've even hit your view.